# My apps been crashing java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth, crash

Bluetooth.class
//method inside this class

```
  private void enableBT() 
  {        
  getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);

 if(!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH)) 
 {
      Log.d(TAG, "ble_not_supported");
      finish();
 }
```

}
}

Comment: Let me know if you want any additional information!

Comment: You need to read further on in the stack trace to determine the issue. That first line doesn't tell much.

Comment: @MikeM. I've posted the error from logcat, could you help?

Comment: It's a nullpointerexception. Google it - it has been asked about a million times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the device supports bluetooth or not.
If you are running this on emulator. The emulator does not generally support bluetooth which will return you a null for

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

You can try using this before the bluetooth operation:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
```

OR

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
```

This will tell you whether the bluetooth feature exists or not.

Comment: I'm running it on an AVD emulator.
The app used to run fine, I don't think it's the bluetooth that causes app crashing. Since I tried running the app by removing bluetooth method itself.
Could you check the logcat?

Comment: This is what Android documentation say about getDefaultAdapter- Get a handle to the default local Bluetooth adapter. Currently Android only supports one Bluetooth adapter, but the API could be extended to support more. This will always return the default adapter or null if Bluetooth is not supported on this hardware platform.

Comment: This is the exception which means null was returned by the method- Attempt to invoke virtual method
'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.enable()' on a null
object reference

Comment: So, i used this line and got rid of it.

getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ble_not_supported");
            finish();
}

However, now i have this error.

com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: aep, destroying layer...